# taking value of one function as input for another function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Function 1

```
df tar_res(data,'target',res)
   df=data.copy()
   if target=='xyz':
     new_data=df.drop(['c'],axis=1)
   elif target=='uhl':
     new_data=df.drop(['f'],axis=1)
   else:
      print("invalid")
   
   if res==6:
      new_data[new_data['h_res']==6]
   elif res==5:
      new_data[new_data['h_res']==5]
   else:
      print("invalid")
   return new_df
```

function 2

```
df train_test(model,tar_res)
   clean_data=tar_res
   X=
   y=
   X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y ,
                                   random_state=104, 
                                   test_size=0.25, 
                                   shuffle=True)
   if model=="randomForestregressor":
      regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0)
      regressor.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
      y_pred=regressor.predict(X_test) 
   return f"rmse:{np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred))}",f"mse:{metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)}",f"mae:{metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test,y_pred)}"
```

**I want to know how I can assign variable X and Y in function 2.**
***X="everything except target variable selected in tar_res function"**
**Y="target variable selected in tar_res function"***

Comment: You can't access local variables inside another function.The only way would be to return the variables from the function to the caller.

Comment: @JohnGordon   returning new_df,target will give me a dataframe,target. How should I assign target from return newdf,target to Y and new_df to clean_data in function 2.